# I am struggling to iterate through an array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I am simply trying to print a list of what is an my array into another div. 
It does not seem to be working.
The code is below

```
import React from "react";
import "./navbar.css";

class Navbar extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const categories = ["Art", "Films", "Brands", "Restaraunts"];
    var categoryList = categories.forEach(function(category){
              return <div className='navbar-item'>{category}</div>;
          })
    // Real thing would equal const category = this.props.category.name;
    return(
      <div className='navbar'>
          { categoryList }
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: there is no error when I run this. However, nothing returns leaving an empty div

Answer (score 4):

Small issue. Replace `forEach` with `map()`:

```js
var categoryList = categories.map(function (category) {
  return (
    <div className='navbar-item'>{category}</div>
  );
});
```

**Difference between `forEach` and `map`**

Let’s first take a look at the definitions on MDN:

- `forEach()` — executes a provided function once for each array element.
- `map()` — creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**What exactly does this mean?**

Well, the `forEach()` method doesn’t actually return anything (undefined). It simply calls a provided function on each element in your array. This callback is allowed to **mutate** the calling array.

Meanwhile, the `map()` method will also call a provided function on every element in the array. The difference is that `map()` utilizes return values and actually **returns a new Array** of the same size.

**Improvements**

Also, quick suggestion, if I may? Use arrow functions.

```js
var categoryList = categories.map(category => (
  <div className='navbar-item'>{category}</div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`. map returns a new array, forEach doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct here, also worth adding that when returning a list like this React will nag you to add a key (this is due to how React handles indexes with element lists). A simple way to do this is to pass the key from the map.

Borrowing from the other examples you would end up with:

```
var categoryList = categories.map((category, key) => (
  <div key={key} className='navbar-item'>{category}</div>
);
```

It's worth noting that with this key, it will most likely not be very unique, especially in a complex application, and so tools eslint may insist you create one that is.